# Prove $\int^\infty_0 b\sin(\frac{1}{bx})-a\sin(\frac{1}{ax}) \mathrm d x= -\ln(\frac{b}{a})$ using Frullani integrals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

Prove $$\int^\infty_0 b\sin(\frac{1}{bx})-a\sin(\frac{1}{ax}) \mathrm dx= -\ln(\frac{b}{a})$$

I'm supposed to use Frullani integrals which states that $\int^\infty_0 \frac{f(bx)-f(ax)}{x}\mathrm dx$ since this equals $[f(\infty)-f(0)] \ln(\frac{b}{a})$

So I need to get the first equation into the form of the Frullani integral. I can't figure out how to make this transformation though because I'm no good at them.

Comment: Wait, you cannot find $f$ such that $b\sin(1/bx)-a\sin(1/ax)=(f(bx)-f(ax))/x$ for every $x$?

Comment: @Did Exactly, am I missing something obvious?

Comment: YES! $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prove $\int^\infty_0 \frac{\frac{1}{1+(bx)^2}-\frac{1}{1+(ax)^2}}{x}dx = ln(\frac{a}{b})$ with Frullani Integrals](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130044/prove-int-infty-0-frac-frac11bx2-frac11ax2xdx-ln-fra)

Comment: @Did Care to give me a hint? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: $$\color{red}{bx}\sin(1/\color{red}{bx})-\color{blue}{ax}\sin(1/\color{blue}{ax})=f(\color{red}{bx})-f(\color{blue}{ax})$$

Comment: @Did You should really write down an answer with that.

Comment: I've solved it now anyway. :)

Answer (score 2):

> It suffices to take $ f(x) =\frac{\sin x}{x}$ and applies Frullani's theorem thereafter.

Setting, $u =\frac1x$ then $dx=-\frac{du}{u^2}$

$$\int^\infty_0 b\sin(\frac{1}{bx})-a\sin(\frac{a}{ax})dx =\int^\infty_0 \frac{b\sin(\frac{x}{b})-a\sin(\frac{x}{a})}{x^2}dx \\=\int^\infty_0 \frac{\frac bx\sin(\frac{x}{b})-\frac ax\sin(\frac{x}{a})}{x}dx = \frac{f(\frac{x}{b})- f(\frac{x}{a})}{x}dx =f(0)\ln\left(\frac{\frac1b}{\frac1a}\right).$$

Where, $$ f(x) =\frac{\sin x}{x}\to 1 ~~as ~~x\to 0$$ satisfies conditions of Frullani's Theorem.

$$\color{red}{\int^\infty_0 b\sin(\frac{1}{bx})-a\sin(\frac{a}{ax})dx  =\ln\left(\frac{\frac1b}{\frac1a}\right) =\ln\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) }.$$